# Angular Material md-chips with md-autocomplete: Event md-not-found not work with md-transform-chip

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm working with Angular Material v1.0.7 and I have trouble with md-chips:

In md-chips, I use md-autocomplete ( ... ). Here is my situation:
 - When user input vaue in md-autocomplete, if there are no items, user can press Enter to create new chip. Another way, if there are no items, a md-not-found will display that "There are no items fit, click here to add New item". In Controller, I can catch event when user click to text "There are no items fit, click here to add New item". But when I call to function md-transform-chip (I want my user click to text "There are no items fit, click here to add New item" is same with press Enter.), it's not working.

Here is codepen:

```
codepen.io/DieuNQ/pen/oxoNVe?editors=1010
```

Is there any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that you ask a question in a way that others understand at the moment your question is not clear

Comment: You can open this codepen. When you input a text in textbox and press "Enter" a new chip will be created. I just want: when user input a text in textbox and click "Not found. Click here to add" dialog --> It will create a new Chip - like when user press Enter

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack that might just work for you,as we are making use of `md-auto-complete` we currently don't have a way to tell `md-auto-complete` to add a `chip` on click of `md-not-found` element.

hack : with this directive we look for `click` on window and then add a new item as chip.

```
.directive('mdChips', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'mdChips', // Extends the original mdChips directive
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, mdChipsCtrl) {

      var mouseUpActions = [];

      mdChipsCtrl.onInputBlur = function(event) {
        this.inputHasFocus = false;

        mouseUpActions.push((function() {
          var chipBuffer = this.getChipBuffer();
          if (chipBuffer != "") { // REQUIRED, OTHERWISE YOU'D GET A BLANK CHIP
            this.appendChip(chipBuffer);
            this.resetChipBuffer();
          }
        }).bind(this));
      };

      window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        while (mouseUpActions.length > 0) {
          var action = mouseUpActions.splice(0, 1)[0];
          $timeout(function() {
            $timeout(action);
          });
        }
      }, false);
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/mPqazv) .

Comment: Hi @Rishab777: Thank you. It worked. Just one issue: You insert in textbox --> click out-side --> click to text, then text is added to a new chip.

I have another solution: when user click to dialog not found, we trigger event keypress Enter. Look like this solution is better. However, I tried today but no luck. But I think It should work.

Comment: can you alter it a bit and do the needed but I feel the above directive should serve your requirements. Mark the question as answered and close the question.